# Summarise dates by month - excel

Tags: excel, date, summary

Ive got a column of dates dd/mm/yyyy, im trying to summaries them by month and year. Eg. if i have `01/01/2012, 23/01/2012` i would like to have a summary table showing `01/2012 | 2`.

Is there a simple way to do this ? At the moment im trying to copy the full date, reformat it only to show mm/yyyy and then run a `countif` formula, but it seems a complex way to do it, or is this the right way ?

Comment: IMO - one of the quickest ways would be to format the date column to mm/yyyy and use the COUNTIF() formula as you suggested.  (Unless you can dump into a database such as SQL Server, then possibilities are endless)

Comment: use a Pivot table, then Group dates into Months, and Years

Answer (score 1):

Use the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) with [EDATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) supplying the upper boundary.

With `01/01/2012` in C2 (with a cell format of `mm/yyyy`) put this in D2,

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">="&C2,A:A, "<"&EDATE(C2, 1))
```

[image: countifs_edate]